# What is more probable? To split into 2 or 3 categories

Tags: probability

I am learning Quantum Mechanics and my colleague asked me a question related to probabilities. I believe it is a math question because it tackles probabilities.

---

Those familiar with the concept of measuring spin can skip this part:

If a particle is spin up or spin down, and I measure it on the z-axis, my apparatus will give me up or down respectively. If it's right or left, and I measure it on the y-axis, my apparatus will give me right or left respectively. If it's in or out, and I measure it on the x-axis, my apparatus will give me in or our respectively.

But, if it was on a different axis than the one I'm measuring it on, it will give me a random spin. For example, it was spin up and I measured it on the x-axis, I have 50% chance to measure it in, and 50% chance to measure it out.

---

Assume I have 12 particles. What I know about them is they all have the same spin, but I don't know in which  of the 3 direction (x, y, or z), and I want to know in what axis they are pointing.

Which is better?

- Split them evenly into two categories. Measure the first one in the z, and the second one in the y. If I find a category's spin completely in the same direction, then this is the original axis. If both pointed in one direction, I choose randomly between them. Otherwise it's the third unmeasured axis.
- Split them into 3 categories. Measure each with a different axis. The one that gives me spin pointing in one direction is the original axis. If more than one gave me one direction, then I choose randomly between them.

Comment: This could be framed as a coin flip problem - you have 3 coins, two of which are fair, and one of which is either two-headed or two-tailed. You can flip coins a total of 12 times, and want to identify which is the unfair coin with the highest probability. Is it better to flip two coins 6 times each, or each coin 4 times?

Comment: My QM is rusty, but I'm not sure you have understood how this works. If a particle is in an eigenstate with its spin along the x-axis there is no way to find this out definitively. Of course if you measure its spin along the x axis you will get +1 but this will also be true (with p=50%) if its spin is along the y- or z-axes. So when you say "If I find a category's spin completely in the same direction" I'm not sure what you mean. You can measure the spin, but this will not definitively tell you where the spin was before you measured it. Indeed, it may not have had a well defined spin at all.